# Passing a Value from App to ContentView in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, observable, menuitem

I find a lot of resources out there as to how to let the user select a menu item and then open a folder.  The following is what I have.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Oh_My_App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: 480.0, height: 320.0)
        }.commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                Button {
                    if let url = showFileOpenPanel() {
                        print(url.path)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Open file...")
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("O")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showFileOpenPanel() -> URL? {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.title = "Selecting a folder..."
        openPanel.message = "Please select a folder containing one or more files."
        let response = openPanel.runModal()
        return response == .OK ? openPanel.url : nil
    }
}
```

Okay.  That's no problem.  I can print the file path.  Well, my actual question is how to return this value to `ContentView`? It is `ContentView` that is virtually running the show in this sample application.  So I use `ObservableObject` as follows.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Oh_My_App: App {
    @StateObject var menuObservable = MenuObservable()
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }.commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                Button {
                    menuObservable.openFile()
                } label: {
                    Text("Open file...")
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("O")
            }
        }
    }
}

class MenuObservable: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
    func openFile() {
        if let openURL = showFileOpenPanel() {
            fileURL = openURL
        }
    }
    
    func showFileOpenPanel() -> URL? {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.title = "Selecting a folder..."
        openPanel.message = "Please select a folder containing one or more files."
        let response = openPanel.runModal()
        return response == .OK ? openPanel.url : nil
    }
}
// ContentView.swift //
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var menuObservable = MenuObservable()
    @State var filePath: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello: \(filePath)")
            }.onChange(of: menuObservable.fileURL) { newValue in
                filePath = newValue.path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `ContentView` won't get updated.  So how do I get `ContentView` to receive a value from the menu call from `App`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're creating a *new instance* of `MenuObservable` in `ContentView`, so it doesn't have any connection to the instance that received the menu command. You need to pass a reference to your existing instance (ie the one owned by `Oh_My_App`).

In your `ContentView`, change `@ObservedObject var menuObservable = MenuObservable()` to:

```
@ObservedObject var menuObservable : MenuObservable
```

And in your `Oh_My_App`:

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView(menuObservable: menuObservable)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I guess I was in the right direction.  Or...  Is that how you would do it to return a value to `ContentView`?

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the approach I would use to share state with `ContentView` (which is I assume what you mean by "return a value to...").